# Outlook 2010 error "There was a prob lem starting PhotoViewer.DLL"

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, windows-photo-viewer

I have Outlook 2010 installed on this brand new Windows 7 desktop. When we get an email with an attachment and double-click it, we get an error: "There was a problem starting PhotoViewer.DLL" blah-blah. See attached:

[image]

Note that if I drag this attachment to the desktop and double-click it there it opens it just fine in the Windows default photo viewer.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Does that DLL exist? Also check if you have any Photo Viewer related [add-ins in Outlook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/view-manage-and-install-add-ins-in-office-programs-HA010354315.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Open a command prompt (cmd.exe) with [admin rights](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token) and run [sfc /scannow](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) to check Windows for *damaged and missing Windows files*.